# R: How to duplicate specific rows based on one column and invert values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data set like this

```
ID     departure_airport   arrival_airport   n
1      ZRH                 BUD               1
2      ZRH                 MSY               2
3      MSY                 IAD               2
4      VIE                 ZRH               1
```

I would like to duplicate the rows with a value of 2 in column "n" and invert their airport codes in the departure and arrival columns. The output should look like this:

```
ID     departure_airport   arrival_airport   n
1      ZRH                 BUD               1
2      ZRH                 MSY               2
3      MSY                 ZRH               2
4      MSY                 IAD               2
5      IAD                 MSY               2
6      VIE                 ZRH               1
```

Any suggestions on how I can get the resulting table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter all rows where n equals 2 and `rbind` it to your data.frame in a different order:

`rbind(df1, df1[df1$n == 2, c(1, 3, 2, 4)])`

Answer (score 0):

### dplyr approach

I think `dplyr` offers several readable methods for doing this, but in this case I'd do:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat |>
    filter(n == 2) |>
    rename(
        departure_airport = arrival_airport,
        arrival_airport = departure_airport
    ) |>
    bind_rows(dat) |>
    select(names(dat)) |>
    arrange(ID)

#   ID departure_airport arrival_airport n
# 1  1               ZRH             BUD 1
# 2  2               MSY             ZRH 2
# 3  2               ZRH             MSY 2
# 4  3               IAD             MSY 2
# 5  3               MSY             IAD 2
# 6  4               VIE             ZRH 1
```

Assumes your data is called `dat` obviously.

### base R approach

Alternatively, for a base R approach where the output is the desired order, and that uses column names rather than indeces, you could do:

```r
l  <- dat |>
    split(~ID) |>
    lapply(\(df) {
    if(df$n == 2) {
        df[2,]  <- df[c("ID", "arrival_airport", "departure_airport", "n")]
    }
    df
}) 

do.call(rbind, l)

#       ID departure_airport arrival_airport n
# 1      1               ZRH             BUD 1
# 2.2    2               ZRH             MSY 2
# 2.2.1  2               MSY             ZRH 2
# 3.3    3               MSY             IAD 2
# 3.2    3               IAD             MSY 2
# 4      4               VIE             ZRH 1
```